# How can I seal the hole where a sewage pipe enters a holding tank?

Tags: plumbing

In the yard adjacent to my (new) home is a sewage pit.  It appears that when the plumbing to the upper stories needed to be replaced (many years ago), rather than repairing properly, a hole was made in the cover of the pit to allow the pipe to drain into the pit.

Unfortunately the hole was made pretty large, and the bugs and smells are a problem.

This is a rough diagram of the problematic area:

[image: pl]

blue = cover
red = vertical pipe
black = walls (some walls have windows)
green = open sewage

I can apply plaster/caulk to the open areas and edges, using wood or plastic to cover the larger areas, but that would be a nightmare if (when) access is needed.

How can I seal the hole (green area) without making access to the pipes difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Make a removable section of pipe like 3 feet or 1 meter so that once that section is removed then the lid or cover can be opened.

The bottom section can then be sealed effectively and permanently to the lid reducing the smells.

Sliding joints may work, but I can only suggest...

So, if my explanation was too poor, this diagram may help, clamping or securing I leave to you :

[image]

Comment: sorry if this is an ignorant question, but how would one make a removable section of pipe?

Comment: @ccc added diagram does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Call your county health dept for an inspection before you do anything. It could be that the previous owner/contractor-builder/inspector is liable to repair/replace. I am NOT a lawyer, but know that these issues can get expensive/ugly FAST. Any 'patches' are unlikely to block gases/odor in my opinion.